# How to make tic tac toe in Python using turtle without the number system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, tic-tac-toe, python-turtle

I am making a tic/tac/toe game and I was wondering how this type of game can be made without using the number system?

Most examples Ive seen use numbers to correspond to the user and the computer competing against each other on the game board. Like "0-9". Then thats how they decide the winner. Is there any other way without using any built-in methods? I am just using the turtle module, the random module and the time module.

So far this is my code. I am trying to create a function that controls the computers moves then check game over for three in a row pattern without using the number system:

```
import turtle
import random
import time

# draw board
pieces = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
turn = "X"

turtle.clear()
turtle.setup(600, 600)
turtle.bgcolor("black")

turtle.color("white")
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.width(10)
turtle.up()

# Horizontal bars
turtle.goto(-300, 100)
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.up()
turtle.goto(-300, -100)
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.up()

# Vertical bars
turtle.goto(-100, 300)
turtle.setheading(-90)
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.up()
turtle.goto(100, 300)
turtle.down()
turtle.forward(600)
turtle.up()

turtle.color("green")

# Draw noughts and crosses
def cross(x, y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x + 20, y - 20)
    turtle.setheading(-45)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(226)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x + 180, y - 20)
    turtle.setheading(-135)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(226)
    turtle.up()

def circle(x, y):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x + 100, y - 180)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.circle(80)
    turtle.up()

turtle.update()

def drawPieces(pieces):
    x, y = -300, 300

    for piece in pieces:
        if piece == "X":
            cross(x, y)
        elif piece == "O":
            circle(x, y)

        x += 200
        if x > 100:
            x = -300
            y -= 200

def clicked(x, y):
    global turn, pieces

    turtle.onscreenclick(None)  # disable handler when inside handler!

    column = (x + 300) // 200
    row = (y - 300) // -200
    square = int(row * 3 + column)

    print("You clicked ", x, ",", y, " which is square ", square)

    if pieces[square] == "_":
        pieces[square] = turn

        if turn == "X":
            turn = "O"
        else:
            turn = "X"

        drawPieces(pieces)
    else:
        print("That square is already taken")

    turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)

# Start the game
turtle.tracer(0,0)
turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)
turtle.mainloop()
```

Thank you! Any help is appreciated. Hope this was clear enough.

Comment: No, the question is not clear enough. At what point are you failing? Where is your problem? Do you have Problems checking for solutions?

Comment: Yes because as I research solutions for the game. Mostly everyone has the "choose number between 0 and 9" and thats what they use to have the user compete against the computer. However, thats not what i want. I am trying to figure out how to use the random module. Though I havent seen any clear examples of that being used. And thats why my original question asked if there was "any other way to create a tic tac toe game without using a number system?"

Comment: What do you mean by 'number system'? This is a computer. You _have_ to assign some numbers to the fields to implement it. (You already have) Where would you use number and want to avoid them. (The `random` modules also only works on numbers). Do you want to create a computer player?

Comment: Yeah thats what I am trying to do create a computer player.

Comment: And really? Then wouldnt using ```random``` be a lot easier? I have not found any examples

Comment: How would you use random without numbers? What do you mean with 'Number system'?

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I am just wondering why I havent seen any examples WITH ```random```. All I see is long if-statements for each number and Im wondering if using random would be shorter and more concise

Comment: random wouldn't make a perfect player. Tic-Tac-Toe is small [solved game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game), so you get a free perfect player that always wins or draws. Yes, random would be shorter, but not as good.

Comment: Okay, well before I get to perfect stylistic code. I just wanted to try something with ```random```. Thats all.

Comment: Ok, then do that.

Comment: Please read [ask] - you seem to be stuck in your design phase, showing a wall of code and no clear specific error / problem. If you want to do it with random, use it. If you get a specific problem, research it. If you are still stuck, make a [mcve] and present your problem. SO is not suited for "designing" your game, better for specific problems we can help solve. We would need to code your complete game logic for you - thats not what SO is for....

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example of a Tic-Tac-Toe game where the computer plays by picking random squares and the code tries to avoid numbers as much as possible.  It has the ability to detect, and announce, a winner:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import choice

SQUARE_SIZE = 200
FONT_SIZE = 160
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
GAME_SIZE = 3

class TicTacToe:

    wins = [
        [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True],
        [True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False],
        [False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, False],
        [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True],
        [True, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, True],
        [False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, False]
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [Turtle('square', visible=False) for _ in range(GAME_SIZE * GAME_SIZE)]
        self.background = Turtle('square', visible=False)

    def drawBoard(self):
        screen.tracer(False)

        self.background.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE * GAME_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
        self.background.color('black')
        self.background.stamp()

        for j in range(GAME_SIZE):
            for i in range(GAME_SIZE):
                square = self.board[i + j * GAME_SIZE]
                square.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
                square.color('white')
                square.penup()
                square.goto((i - 1) * (SQUARE_SIZE + 2), (j - 1) * (SQUARE_SIZE + 2))
                square.state = None
                square.onclick(lambda x, y, s=square: self.mouse(s))
                square.showturtle()
                square.stamp()  # blank out background behind turtle (for later)

        screen.tracer(True)

    def select(self, square, turn):
        square.onclick(None)  # disable further moves to this square
        square.state = turn
        # replace square/turtle with (written) X or O
        square.hideturtle()
        square.color('black')
        square.sety(square.ycor() - FONT_SIZE / 2)
        square.write(turn, align='center', font=FONT)

        return self.is_winner(turn)

    def is_winner(self, turn):
        for win in self.wins:
            for index, flag in enumerate(win):
                if flag and self.board[index].state != turn:
                    break

            else:  # no break
                self.deactivate()
                screen.textinput("Game Over", turn + " Wins!")
                return True

        return False

    def deactivate(self):
        for square in self.board:
            if square.state is None:
                square.onclick(None)

    def mouse(self, square):

        if self.select(square, 'X'):
            return

        choices = [square for square in self.board if square.state is None]

        if not choices:
            self.deactivate()
            return

        if self.select(choice(choices), 'O'):
            return

screen = Screen()

game = TicTacToe()
game.drawBoard()

screen.mainloop()
```

A table like `wins` might be used to implement a strategy if/when you want to make the computer player smarter.

Comment: That makes sense. So, ```mouse``` I assume controls the moves of both the user and computer. ```is_winner``` checks who wins. ```select``` checks for user clicks? And what does ```deactivate``` do?

Comment: @CollegeStudent101, once the game is over, `deactivate()` removes the event handler from all unclaimed squares, if any, so you can't click on them.  The `select()` method doesn't check for user clicks, it converts a square from being unclaimed to claimed.